# Ajax call is not binding all model properties

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-binding

I am going to create table using jquery on the basis of selection in dropdownlist..When I select any option in dropdown the blank table will be generated on the screen..But when i insert values in blank table and press submit then in action I got model but that model consist only properties in the table which I have added from Ajax..But it ignores value of dropdownlist which I have selected first..If I remove that ajax success code then it gives model with proper values but I wont get values in Table created by ajax success....

Here is my ajax code:

```
 $("#Award").change(function () {
        var selectdAward = $("#Award").val();
        $('#criteriaTable').empty();
        var ServiceUrl = "/Nomination/CriteriasForAward?awardId=" + selectdAward;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: ServiceUrl,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                alert(xhr.responseText)
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#criteriaTable').append('<tr><th>Id</th><th>Criteria-Description</th><th>Comment</th></tr>');

                for (var key in data) {
                    $('#criteriaTable tr:last')
                        .after('<tr><td><label>' + data[key].Id + '</label></td>' 
                        + '<td><label>' + data[key].Title + '</label></td>'
                        + '<td><input type="text" name=Model.Comments[' + key + '].Comment></td>'
                        + '<td><input type="hidden" name=Model.Comments[' + key + '].Id value=' + data[key].Id + '></td></tr>');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
 public class NominationViewModel
    {
        public int AwardId { get; set; }
        public int ManagerId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        public string SelectResourcesBy { get; set; }  //from project or from department
        public IList<CriteriaCommentViewModel> Comments { get; set; }

        public NominationViewModel()
        {
            Comments = new List<CriteriaCommentViewModel>();   
        }

    }
```

This is navigational property class in view model:

```
 public class CriteriaCommentViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Nomination Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })

            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AwardId, @ViewBag.Awards as SelectList, "Select", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, id = "Award" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AwardId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Resource From", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <label> @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SelectResourcesBy, "Project", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })Project</label>
                <label> @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SelectResourcesBy, "Department", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })Department</label>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Project", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjectID, @ViewBag.ProjectsUnderCurrentUser as SelectList, "Select", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, id = "SelectedProject" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ManagerId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Resource Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserId, @ViewBag.Resources as SelectList, "Select", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, id = "Resources" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <hr />

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Criteria", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="Criterias">
                    <table border="1" id="criteriaTable"></table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="button" value="Save Draft" class="btn btn-default" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
                <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

And this is the controller action on which i m posting values:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddNomination(NominationViewModel model)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Dashboard");
        }
```

Please suggest the way to solve this problem..Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean _not binding all model properties_? What properties? You have not even shown your model or the method your posting to.

Comment: On submit button the post action method will get object of ViewModel which we have rendered on view..That viewmodel should contain all the values entered on view..But in my case it consist only values which we have entered in textboxes created by ajax success

Comment: What `ViewModel` You need to show the relevant code!

Comment: You also need to show the view.

Comment: And show the signature of the method your posting back to. (and it needs to be `name=Comments[' + key + '].Comment>` etc (not `name=Model.Comments[' + key + '].Comment>` - your model does not contain a property named `Model`)

Comment: Yeah..Resolved,..After replacing Model.Comment[..] with only Comment[..]  now it is posting all values to action..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view model does not contain a property named `Model` so you need to modify the code for generating the table html to

```
for (var key in data) {
    $('#criteriaTable tr:last')
        .after('<tr><td><label>' + data[key].Id + '</label></td>' 
        + '<td><label>' + data[key].Title + '</label></td>'
        + '<td><input type="text" name=Comments[' + key + '].Comment></td>'
        + '<td><input type="hidden" name=Comments[' + key + '].Id value=' + data[key].Id + '></td></tr>');
}
```

i.e. remove the `"Model."` prefix from the input's `name` attribute.

Comment: A few side notes: You can remove `new { id = "Award" }` and just use `$("#AwardId").change(function () {` and just use `var selectdAward = $(this).val();` and you should be using `var ServiceUrl = '@Url.Action("CriteriasForAward", "Nomination")';` and in the ajax - `data: { awardId: selectdAward },`